# Fetch all data from array php

Tags: php

This is my code, it retreives data from xampp external database and store it to an array that is parsed to json

```
<?php


/*
* Following code will list all the products
*/

// array for JSON response
$response = array();

// include db connect class
require_once __DIR__ . '/conectaDB.php';

// connecting to db
$db = new DB_CONNECT();

// get all products from products table
$result = mysql_query("select cd.id, cd.dt_ini_camp, cd.dt_fim_camp, cd.descricao, + (select sum(quantidade) from lin_doc where id_cab_doc = cd.id) as qtd from cab_doc cd where cd.id_tipo_doc = 1") or die(mysql_error());


 // check for empty result
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
// looping through all results
// products node



while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

    // temp user array
    $product = array();
    $product["id"] = $row["id"];
    $product["dt_ini_camp"] = $row["dt_ini_camp"];
    $product["dt_fim_camp"] = $row["dt_fim_camp"];
    $product["descricao"] = $row["descricao"];
    $product["qtd"] = $row["qtd"];      



    // push single product into final response array
    $response["cab_doc"] = array();
    array_push($response["cab_doc"], $product);
}




// success
$response["success"] = 1;


// echoing JSON response
echo json_encode($response);
} else {
// no products found
$response["success"] = 0;
$response["message"] = "No products found";

// echo no users JSON
echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

Output:

```
{"cab_doc":[{"id":"69","dt_ini_camp":"2012-12-22","dt_fim_camp":"2012-12-  26","descricao":"cadqadadad","qtd":null}],"success":1}
```

My problem is that this is the last record and i want all, whats missing please help

Comment: Could possibly be because you keep emptying `$response["cab_doc"] = array();` in your loop?

Comment: do i? lol thats not my intention what should i change

Comment: Comment it out of your **`while()`** loop and tell us the results.

Comment: sorry ive commented it and now it shows this Warning: array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\webprojecto4\index_pesagem.php on line 42

Comment: and if i place it outside the loop it shows me a blanck page

Comment: check my answer and try that, then let me know what you get

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this for your **`while()`** loop:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

    // temp user array
    $product = array(
        'id' => $row["id"],
        'dt_ini_camp' => $row["dt_ini_camp"],
        'dt_fim_camp' => $row["dt_fim_camp"],
        'descricao' => $row["descricao"],
        'qtd' => $row["qtd"]
    );

    // push single product into final response array

    array_push($response["cab_doc"], $product);
}
```

Optionally you could try adding it to the **`$response['cab_doc']`** array like this:

```
$response['cab_doc'][] = $product;
```

What does that return for you?

**EDIT:** try this:

```
$response["cab_doc"] = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

    // temp user array
    $product = array(
        'id' => $row["id"],
        'dt_ini_camp' => $row["dt_ini_camp"],
        'dt_fim_camp' => $row["dt_fim_camp"],
        'descricao' => $row["descricao"],
        'qtd' => $row["qtd"]
    );

    // push single product into final response array

    array_push($response["cab_doc"], $product);
}
```

**EDIT #2:**

```
<?php


/*
* Following code will list all the products
*/

// array for JSON response
$response = array();

// include db connect class
require_once __DIR__ . '/conectaDB.php';

// connecting to db
$db = new DB_CONNECT();

// get all products from products table
$result = mysql_query("select cd.id, cd.dt_ini_camp, cd.dt_fim_camp, cd.descricao, + (select sum(quantidade) from lin_doc where id_cab_doc = cd.id) as qtd from cab_doc cd where cd.id_tipo_doc = 1") or die(mysql_error());


 // check for empty result
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
// looping through all results
// products node



$response["cab_doc"] = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

// temp user array
$product = array(
    'id' => $row["id"],
    'dt_ini_camp' => $row["dt_ini_camp"],
    'dt_fim_camp' => $row["dt_fim_camp"],
    'descricao' => $row["descricao"],
    'qtd' => $row["qtd"]
);

// push single product into final response array

array_push($response["cab_doc"], $product);
//or
// $response['cab_doc'][] = $product;
}




// success
$response["success"] = 1;


// echoing JSON response
echo json_encode($response);
} else {
// no products found
$response["success"] = 0;
$response["message"] = "No products found";

// echo no users JSON
echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

Comment: so with this line commented $response["cab_doc"] = array(); and your first resolution it shows an warning array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\webprojecto4\index_pesagem.php on line 43 thats this line here:array_push($response["cab_doc"], $product);

Comment: using $response['cab_doc'][] = $product; it show a blank page

Comment: @user3121133 see recent edit and try again, remember to `var_dump($response)` / `print_r($response)`

Comment: blanck page without var_dump($response). with var dump it shows me the data but then it cant be encoded to json

Comment: @user3121133 You have to encode it to json yourself using **`json_encode()`** as you did previously in your script..

Comment: yes i know but doesnt work with the var_dump or print_r because its not in json format

Comment: Sorry, I'm not following you, what do you mean it doesn't work?

the var_dump/print_r is just as a debugging purpose to see that the array is actually set.

What you can do is replace that with what you had before:

**`$response["success"] = 1; echo json_encode($response);`**

Comment: my output string need to be like this {"cab_doc":[{"id":"69","dt_ini_camp":"2012-12-22","dt_fim_camp":"2012-12-  26","descricao":"cadqadadad","qtd":null}],"success":1} with var dump or print r its like this array(1) { ["cab_doc"]=> array(0) { } } array(1) { ["cab_doc"]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(5) { ["id"]=> string(1) "1" ["dt_ini_camp"]=> string(10) "2012-12-22" ["dt_fim_camp"]=> string(10) "2012-12-24" ["descricao"]=> string(19) "Apoios comunitários" ["qtd"]=> string(8) "4762.000" } } }  and then doesnt work

Comment: @user3121133 look at my previous comment.

Comment: ive read it and i did like y said, but when using var_dump or printr it encodes like this array(1) { ["cab_doc"]=> array(0) { } } array(1) { ["cab_doc"]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(5) { ["id"]=> string(1) "1" ["dt_ini_camp"]=> string(10) "2012-12-22" ["dt_fim_camp"]=> string(10) "2012-12-24" ["descricao"]=> string(19) "Apoios comunitários" ["qtd"]=> string(8) "4762.000" } } }

Comment: and it needs to be like this  {"cab_doc":[{"id":"69","dt_ini_camp":"2012-12-22","dt_fim_camp":"2012-12- 26","descricao":"cadqadadad","qtd":null}],"success":1} otherwise it doesnt work

Comment: @user3121133 [This Comment Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22826882/fetch-all-data-from-array-php/22827115?noredirect=1#comment34816904_22827115)

Comment: sorry dont understand